# Accessing a graph created in C from another application

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, save

I am creating a very large graph in the C language, the construction of which takes quite a significant amount of time (about 10 minutes). To illustrate, here is the structure of the graph:

```
#define N 96
struct Graph {
    struct Node* head[N];
};

struct Node {
    struct Address* address;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* neighbour;
    struct Node* prev;
};
struct Graph* graph = createGraph(addresses, ht);
```

After its creation, I work with it effectively and solve the problems I need. But every time I run the application (including when testing and debugging it), I spend a lot of time waiting for the graph to be built. I would like to be able to build this graph once (maybe in another application), and then work with it in C without wasting time each time building it when launching and debugging my application. What is the best way to organize this?

Trying to write a graph to a file and then read it also takes a lot of time.

Comment: Have you considered _allocating_ contiguous nodes from your own (very large) object pool (array), and connecting them with indexes instead of memory pointers. Once built, simply write/read the ?Mb of entire object pool as needed. Elaborate with something similar for "Addresses" and the "Graph" struct...

Comment: I haven't considered this yet. Do you have an example implementation?

Comment: No, I do not... It's not hard. Grab a big chunk of memory to use as an array of structs. Allocate them as you need them (with a counter). You'll have to change your "build graph" code from using pointers to using array element indices. Write the entire array to disk, then reload it as many times as you want (without recomputing the edges.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 It cannot be written directly to a file unless the `address` member is also changed to something other than a pointer.

Comment: @IanAbbott Without writing the code, I thought I alluded to that in my first answer... No idea what's special about 96 nodes in the `graph` structure is, either...

Comment: @Александр Попов, "Trying to write a graph to a file and then read it also takes a lot of time." --> I suspect your graph routines like `createGraph()` and others are weakly implemented, incurring O(n) time cost instead of O(1).  To improve that, need to see the function details.  10 minutes is too long.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! As part of the commentary, I cannot give the entire code of the graph construction function. When constructing it, a file with data is read and entered into a node (Address), in total there are about 2 million nodes in the graph. The only question was its storage.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your nodes in a doubly linked list.

Why?

This adds a lot of complexity and a lot of extra data ( that needs to be constructed, saved to file, and re-read ) so you better have a very good reason for doing this.  For most graph theory problems, storing the nodes in an array is completely sufficient

```
struct Node* neighbour;
```

I assume this is how you link your nodes together into a graph.  However, this will allow each node to be linked to just one other node.  In most graph's that are used to model real world problems, you will need to links a nod4e to more than one other node.

The code you have posted does not allow you to store any data about the links between nodes.  This will be a huge limit on the usefulness of your data structure.

Finally, why are you coding in C?  All this stuff is a lot easier to code in C++.